# Select the latest 3 records for each ID in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with a composite primary key (`ID`, `Date`) like below.

```
+------+------------+-------+
|  ID  |    Date    | Value |
+------+------------+-------+
|   1  | 1433419200 |   15  |
|   1  | 1433332800 |   23  |
|   1  | 1433246400 |   41  |
|   1  | 1433160000 |   55  |
|   1  | 1432900800 |   24  |
|   2  | 1433419200 |   52  |
|   2  | 1433332800 |   23  |
|   2  | 1433246400 |   39  |
|   2  | 1433160000 |   22  |
|   3  | 1433419200 |   11  |
|   3  | 1433246400 |   58  |
|  ... |    ...     |  ...  |
+------+------------+-------+
```

There is also a separate index on `Date` column. The table is of moderate size, currently ~600k row and growing by ~2k everyday.

I want to do a single SELECT query that returns the latest 3 records (ordered by `Date` timestamp) for each `ID`. For each given `ID`, the `Date` values are always unique, so no need to worry about ties for `Date` here.

I've tried a self-join approach, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12114175/548240), but it took quite a few seconds to run and returned nothing:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.Date, p1.Value FROM MyTable AS p1
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS p2 
ON p1.ID=p2.ID AND p1.Date<=p2.Date
GROUP BY p1.ID
HAVING COUNT(*)<=5
ORDER BY p1.ID, p1.Date DESC;
```

What would be a fast solution here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could look up the three most recent dates for each ID:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Value
FROM MyTable
WHERE Date IN (SELECT Date
               FROM MyTable AS T2
               WHERE T2.ID = MyTable.ID
               ORDER BY Date DESC
               LIMIT 3)
```

Alternatively, look up the third most recent date for each ID, and use it as a limit:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Value
FROM MyTable
WHERE Date >= IFNULL((SELECT Date
                      FROM MyTable AS T2
                      WHERE T2.ID = MyTable.ID
                      ORDER BY Date DESC
                      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2),
                     0)
```

Both queries should get good performance from the primary key's index.

Comment: this is a different approach, and very good one too. The performance is 10x better!

Answer (score 3):

First, here is the correct query for the inequality method:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.Date, p1.Value
FROM MyTable p1 LEFT JOIN
     MyTable AS p2 
     ON p1.ID = p2.ID AND p2.Date <= p1.Date
--------------------------^ fixed this condition
GROUP BY p1.ID, p1.Date, p1.Value
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5
ORDER BY p1.ID, p1.Date DESC;
```

I'm not sure if there is a fast way to do this in SQLite.  In most other databases, you can use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.  In MySQL, you can use variables.  Both of these are difficult in SQLite.  Your best solution may be to use a cursor.

The above can benefit from an index on `MyTable(Id, Date)`.

Comment: actually the 'optional' fix is necessary. I've just tried it, without the extra two `GROUP BY` columns, it'd still return nothing. On the index point, since the `ID` and `Date` form composite primary key, there is an index on them by default. But the query takes almost 18 seconds to run on the table of ~600K rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct x.ID,x.Date,X.Value
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM XXXTable  ) c
    CROSS APPLY (

    select top 3 A.ID,a.Date,Value,[Count] from (
    SELECT distinct ID,Date,Value, ROW_NUMBER()
    over (
        PARTITION BY ID
        order by Date
    ) AS [Count]  where c.ID = t.ID


    ) A  order by [Count] desc
```